# PayPal auto return takes ten seconds, is it possible to avoid?

Tags: paypal

I am implementing a PayPal button in a website using at first the sandbox, I am using the new type of button generated with this: http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/

By going to [My Profile > Website payment preferences](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments) (sandbox), I can turn on Auto Return:

[image]

This seems to work but at the end of a transaction I get this:

[image]

I am wondering if that is possible to avoid this?

I'm guessing this is possible using the API instead of the button but I'm looking for the least complicated way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is with the API -- most notably the Express Checkout API with SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole